How to integrate irregularly sampled 3D data along a single axis in python
I have an external program (ComSol) which provides me with a list of samples of some function f(x,y,z).
I wish to compute the integral of f(x,y,z) through the z axis, $\int_ a^b f(x,y,z) dz$.
The output data provided is structured as four vectors -  x,y,z which correspond to the sampling points and a vector vals which is the value of the function at those points.
The samples are not uniform, the sampling density is increased at locations where the function is quickly varying and lowered where the function is approximately constant.
The following code creates an equivalent scenario, with some f(x,y,z) as some basic function:
import numpy as np

def f(x,y,z) :
    "function to be integrated"
    return x**2 + y**2 + z**2



#generate some random non-uniform sampling points
n_points = 10000
x = np.random.random_sample(n_points)
y = np.random.random_sample(n_points)
z = np.random.random_sample(n_points)

vals = f(x,y,z)

My attempt to solve this problem was to interpolate the provided data onto a uniform grid which I could then simply integrate using simpson's method.
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define a uniform grid to interpolate the data onto
n_interp_points = 25
x_interp = np.linspace(0,1,n_interp_points)
y_interp = np.linspace(0,1,n_interp_points)
z_interp = np.linspace(0,1,n_interp_points)

X_interp, Y_interp, Z_interp = np.meshgrid(x_interp,y_interp,z_interp)

#scipy linear interpolator with triangular basis function
tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(np.stack([x,y,z],axis=1)) #precompute triangles

interpolator = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(tri,vals,fill_value=0) #create interpolator function
vals_interp = interpolator((X_interp,Y_interp,Z_interp)) #interpolate onto defined grid

#integrate the interpolated function along the z axis with simpson's method
result = scipy.integrate.simpson(y=vals_interp,x=z_interp,axis=2)


#make comparison plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2,constrained_layout=True,)
for ax in axes.ravel() :
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

#plot expected result
def integral_f_dz(x,y,a,b) :
    "analytical expression of definite integral of f through z axis"
    return 1/3 * ( -a**3 + 3*(b-a)*(x**2+y**2)+b**3 )

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_interp, y_interp)

axes[0].set_title("Analytically generated\nresult")
axes[0].contourf(xx, yy, integral_f_dz(xx,yy,0,1))

#plot the result from interpolation and integration
axes[1].set_title("Result from interpolation\nand integration")
axes[1].contourf(xx, yy, result)

The resulting plots look as follows:

This solution technically works however since I have a function which is quickly varying in some areas, using a uniform grid is not desirable. In order to achieve accurate results I would need a gridsize which is so large it becomes memory and CPU intensive to perform both the interpolation and integration steps.
What I am looking for is a way to perform the integral with my non-uniformly sampled data without having to perform the integration. I am sure there are many algorithms which can do this, but I have not been able to work out which of these are for my specific case or how to get them to work.
Note: I can increase the number of sampling points in my dataset so my issue is with how to handle the data as it is formatted and to perform the integration on a non-uniform grid, and not that I do not have enough sample points to accurately perform the integral.
